# mod_rewrite rules for a site hosted in a directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that i am building in a directory, not in the root of my webserver.

```
I would like  http://localhost/mysite/index.php?view=home

to rewrite to http://localhost/mysite/home
```

I can't get it to work

trying this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Make sure you also have `Options FollowSymLinks` enabled. I once was kicking myself for hours because I forgot it and didn't notice

Comment: It looks good. Are .htaccess overrides enabled? I mean, are you certain your .htaccess is even being considered by Apache?

Comment: yes, i can get it to load my site and rewrite the URL easy enough, but it's not passing the argument. I think it would work if i was on the root of the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
```

many thanks to http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/